# How to exclude file when fixing a zip archive

Tags: zip

I would like to exclude some files when fixing my zip archive. But following doesn't seem to work:

```
zip -FF old.zip --out new.zip -x \*.JPG
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip -FF` runs a [specific block of dedicated code](https://sources.debian.net/src/zip/3.0-11/zip.c/#L3848), which doesn't handle other options such as `-x`. As a result, you can't run a single `zip` command which combines `-FF` and any other operation.

To get the `new.zip` you're after, you'd need to run

```
zip -FF old.zip --out new.zip
zip -d new.zip \*.JPG
```